# How can I mount an AES-128 encrypted DMG file using the NTFS file system under Windows XP?

Tags: windows, mac, ntfs, dmg-image

I found HFSExplorer, which can handle encrypted DMG files, but it only supports HFS, and the DMG I want to open is NTFS. I can't just use any image mounter since the DMG file is encrypted, and I don't want to need to copy it over to my main hard drive first. (The DMG is on an external hard drive.) If copying it is the only way, however, I'd be willing to settle for that, but I'd rather just leave it on the external hard drive in an encrypted form.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you used an Apple-proprietary disk image format to image a Microsoft-proprietary filesystem for mounting on a Microsoft OS. Why did you stick Apple in the middle of that instead of going with a Micrsoft->*Microsoft*->Microsoft solution.

Comment: I hadn't really given it any thought. I know a DMG file is really just a plain disk image, but I don't know how the encryption is done.

Answer (score 1):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Disk_Image#Data_format):

> The encrypted layer was reverse engineered in an implementation called [VileFault](http://dekstop.de/weblog/2007/01/dmg_encryption_reverse_engineered/) (A spoonerism of FileVault), and dmg2img and DMGExtractor have since implemented support for encrypted images.

Use [dmg2img](http://vu1tur.eu.org/tools/dmg2img-1.6.2-win32.zip) or [DMGExtractor](http://www.catacombae.org/dmgx.html) to convert the encrypted dmg into a regular one. This removes the outer encryption layer which is independent of the actual filesystem stored inside the `dmg`. Then, if it's NTFS, use an app that can mount a raw disk image in Windows (this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/244803/how-do-i-mount-an-ntfs-image-created-by-gnu-ntfsclone-on-windows) suggests that you can use [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) to do that).

Using HFSExplorer will probably not work if it only works with HFS volumes.